# how to fix the "warped characters" issue in a haskell project?

Tags: haskell

i cloned this haskell-based blog project:

git clone https://phabricator.chromabits.com/diffusion/B/blog blog-by-chromabits

i setup a blog successfully: http://cb.smt.biz.st ,but a post written in chinese has "warped characters",the post is http://cb.smt.biz.st/posts/2016/08/13/test-1/ ,

how to fix this "warped characters" issue?

Comment: What does "warped characters" mean? As someone who doesn't read chinese, I look at that page and I see stuff that looks like chinese, so I don't know what issue you are trying to fix.

Comment: @amalloy,those are not chinese.see this article: http://kunststube.net/encoding/ ,i mean "encoding error". which file in the repo https://phabricator.chromabits.com/diffusion/B/blog should i edit to use utf-8 encoding ?

Answer (score 2):

Your website is encoded in UTF-8, and does in fact contain proper chinese text. Your problem is that the website doesn't advertise that it is encoded that way, therefore any browser you'll use will simply take an educated guess (which will often be wrong). For example, Chrome on Windows 10 picks Windows-1252 as the character encoding for me, which is of course wrong. A browser on linux might default to UTF-8 instead, so a user like that might not see anything wrong.

A simple bandaid fix for this would be to simply state the encoding in the html header:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

that will fix it for that page at least. Going forward you should set up your webserver to send the correct encoding in the HTTP header (it's part of the Content-Type header field, see [here](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index) for details).

You can also tell your browser to use a particular encoding for a website to diagnose issues like this.

Comment: 'A simple bandaid fix for this would be to simply state the encoding in the html header:

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
that will fix it for that page at least. ' -this does works.thank u